# How to search a pattern in last 10 minutes of log using a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a log file monitor in Powershell. The requirement is to search a pattern in most recent (last 10 minutes log prints) in a log file using Powershell.
The format of log file is as follows:

```
20/04/2018 23:15:28: some information
20/04/2018 23:16:28: some information
20/04/2018 23:17:28: some information
:
20/04/2018 23:55:28: some information
20/04/2018 23:56:28: some information
```

So for example the script runs at 23:58 then it should search a pattern in log prints between '20/04/2018 23:48'  and  '20/04/2018 23:48' only.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far? We do not write ready to use code on request. I assume you know that Powershell can calculate with DateTime objects, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the last few entries, say 10, from a text file like this:

```
Get-Content .\data.txt -Tail 10
```

Of course, this may not be from the last 10 minutes. Here is one option to do that:

```
Get-Content .\data.txt |
        ForEach-Object {$threshold = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)}{
            if($_ -match "^(?<timestamp>(\d{2}/){2}\d{4} (\d{2}:){2}\d{2}):.*$")
            {
                if((Get-Date $Matches.timestamp) -gt $threshold)
                {
                    $_
                }
            }           
        }
```

Of course, the pattern match will work for both `mm/dd/yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy` date formats as the structure is the same.  However, you may get difficulties with `Get-Date` parsing the pattern if the file uses the opposite to your system.  For example, the format in your example would work fine in the UK (`dd/mm/yyyy`), but will likely fail in the USA (`mm/dd/yyyy`) - I've not tested it, just warning based on previous issues with dates.