# Get-Date less than date/string from text file

Tags: powershell

I have written some code that parses warranty information about a license from a website into a .txt file. My goal (and problem) is to compare the warranty expiry date from a .txt file with the current date, in order to know if warranty has expired.

I am a powershell beginner so my code might not be very logical, but this is what I have so far:

```
#the Invoke-WebRequest is up here which outputs into $output_file

#files
$output_file = ‘c:\warrantyinfo.txt’
$warranty_file = 'c:\warrantydate.txt'

#At this point all the warranty information is in $output_file
#With the code below I do a select string to get the information I want and 
#get rid of everything else
$warrantyUntil = Get-Content $output_file
$warrantyUntil | Select-String '("toCustomerDate":)["]\d{4}\-(0?[1- 
9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object 
{$_.Matches} | Select value > $warranty_file

#I now have "toCustomerDate":"yyyy-mm-dd in a new .txt file 
#Below I try to grab just the date in the format yyyy-mm-dd in order to 
#compare with todays date. I think this is where I go wrong.
$warrantyDate=Select-String -Path $warranty_file -Pattern "\d{4}\-(0?[1- 
9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*" -AllMatches | Foreach-Object 
{$_.Matches} | Select value

#Current date in the format I want
$currentDate=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"

#Compare warrantyDate and currentDate to decide if warranty has expired or 
#not
if ($currentDate -lt $warrantyDate) {
Write-Host "Warranty is valid"
} else {
Write-Host "Warranty has expired"
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are comparing two strings and expecting a date comparison: `$currentDate -lt $warrantyDate`.  Convert `$currentDate` and `$warrantyDate` to `DateTime` objects (i.e. use `Get-Date`),then compare the.  My answer to a similar  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951064/how-to-search-a-pattern-in-last-10-minutes-of-log-using-a-powershell-script/49951288#49951288) might help you.

Comment: I believe $currentDate is already a DateTime object since I used Get-Date? I think the problem is related to $warrantyDate, ill have to look into how to go about converting it to a DateTime object. thanks

Comment: `$currentDate` is a string because you use `-UFormat`.  Check the official [help documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) (`Output` section) or run `Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d" | Get-Member` and look at the output - a string.  All you really need is `$currentDate = GetDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happens because of data type mismatch.

First of all your `$currentDate` is a string type, while you probably wanted it to be `datetime` type, this is happening because of performed specific formatting. Also `$warrantyDate` is string or even an array of strings. You need to take that in mind too.

You would want to explisitly set data type of initializtion variable by placing proper class acceleration before variable name. Like so:

```
[DateTime]$currentDate=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
[DateTime]$warrantyDate=Select-String -Path $warranty_file -Pattern "\d{4}\-(0?[1- 
9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*" -AllMatches | Foreach-Object 
{$_.Matches} | Select value
```

To see what is variable type use this:

```
$currentDate.GetType().Name
```

Comment: When adding[DateTime] to warrantyDate it attempts to convert "{Value=2020-03-31}" which returns an error: "Cannot convert .. of type Selected.System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match to type System.DateTime

Comment: @Vik `Select value` -> `Select -ExpandProperty value`

Comment: thanks! doing this and adding -ExpandProperty value got it all working as expected

Answer (score 0):

With a file `warrantyinfo.txt`:

```
"toCustomerDate":"2018-04-22"
"toCustomerDate":"2018-04-24"
```

and this script:

```
$currentDate=Get-Date

$output_file = ‘.\warrantyinfo.txt’

$warrantyUntil = Get-Content $output_file | 
  Select-String '(?<="toCustomerDate":)"\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"' -AllMatches

$warrantyUntil
$warrantyUntil.matches.value

$warrantyUntil.matches.value | ForEach {
    if ($currentDate -lt [datetime]$_.trim('"')) {
        Write-Host "Warranty $_ is valid"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Warranty $_ has expired"
    }
}
```

You'll get this sample output:

```
"toCustomerDate":"2018-04-22"
"toCustomerDate":"2018-04-24"
"2018-04-22"
"2018-04-24"
Warranty "2018-04-22" has expired
Warranty "2018-04-24" is valid
```

The script uses a different RegEx with a [positive LookBehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `(?<="toCustomerDate":)` which isn't part of matched value.

Comment: testing this as an alternative, but I don't understand what you're comparing $currentDate with in this line: if ($currentDate -lt [datetime]$_.trim('"')) { ? It gives me a null-valued expression

Comment: here `$warrantyUntil.matches.value` has double quotes attached, the .trim removes them.