# Powershell - Show only the lines in a CSV that are in a period of 15 minutes from the time of running the script

Tags: powershell

In one of my scripts it is generation nearly 100 of lines, while I only need the ones within 15 minutes from running the script.

I did find a script [How to search a pattern in last 10 minutes of log using a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951064/how-to-search-a-pattern-in-last-10-minutes-of-log-using-a-powershell-script)
I changed it and got this:

```
Get-Content .\Downloads\data.txt |
        ForEach-Object {$threshold = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-130).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}{
            if($_ -match "^(?<timestamp>(\d{4}-){2}\d{2}T(\d{2}:){2}\d{2})Z.*$")
            {
                if((Get-Date $Matches.timestamp).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") -gt $threshold)
                {
                    $_
                }
            }           
        }
```

Where i am able to only show the times withing these 15 minutes.
However, as you may see on the script pasted above, the time format in my csv file is not in the correct format. The format they used on the linked page is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", my time format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ" here is an example: "2020-06-04T11:39:01Z"

I have changed the "Get-Date" to show in the correct format, but what im struggling with is the 3rd line.
`if($_ -match "^(?<timestamp>(\d{4}-){2}\d{2}T(\d{2}:){2}\d{2})Z.*$")`
Im not really sure how to go around this, i have tried movingg around the code and more.
Some help would be appreciated and if you know a better way to to this, let me know.

Comment: don't bother using regex. your CSV likely have the timestamp in a consistent location, so grab that location. once you have that use `Get-Date $TimeString`. that format you show is a standard one that the G-D call understands directly. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes my CSV have the timestamp in consistent location, however im not too sure how i would get the result from what you are saying.

Comment: without seeing your CSV - the 1st two or three lines of it - there is no way to give you any more detail that i already have. so, please add that info to your Question & wrap it in code formatting to make it easy to read.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I solved it!. look at the answer, you actually helped my out a little

Comment: kool! glad to help a tad ... and that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how i could do it!

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "<link>" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -expandproperty Links | Sort-Object -property TimestampUtcFromDevice -Descending
$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -start (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) -end ($WebResponse | Select-Object -expandproperty TimestampUtcFromDevice -first 1) 
$WebResponse | Select-Object -First ($Timespan.Minutes) | export-Csv "$FilePath\$FQFL" -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "$delimiter"
```

Pain in the ass but i got it!
The first takes the json from the website and expands a property and sort it.
Then i find how many minutes there are from the latest code and 15 minutes back in time. A great thing i found out from one of the responses was that Get-Date knows the time zone.
The last one selects only the first entries based on the minutes from the last cmdlet, and exports it in a csv file.